# Object doesn't listen to method or is not created? (C++ OO)

Tags: c++

Whenever I try to make an object and call a function on it, it doesn't seem to work.

I have no idea why, since I don't seem to have errors too.

I have searched around on here regarding constructors and the toString-method, but haven't find anything that worked.

I have tried to edit (distinct) the members in the constructor members,
Tried to rewrite the toString method.
Tried to make local object (with no pointer).

But it doesn't return me the things in the object that I created when calling the constructor.

Where does the problem situate in this problem?

Here is my code:

.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Store{

private:
    int id;
    string name;
    string adress;
    string telephone;
    string btwNumber;


public:
    int getId();
    void setId(int);
    string getName();
    void setName(string);
    string getAdress();
    void setAdress(string);
    string getTelephone();
    void setTelephone(string);
    string getBtwNumber();
    void setBtwNumber(std::string);
    string toString();
    Store(int, string, string , string, string);
};
```

.cpp file:

```
// Store.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Store.h"



Store::Store(int idnum, string nameS, string adreS, string telephonE, string btwnummeR){
    idnum = id;
    nameS = name;
    adreS = adress;
    telephonE = telephone;
    btwnummeR = btwNumber;
}


int Store::getId()
{
    return id;
}

void Store::setId(int id){
    this->id = id;
}

string Store::getName(){
    return naam;
}

void Store::setName(string name){
    this->naam = naam;
}

string Store::getTelephone(){
    return telephone;
}

void Store:setTelephone(string telephone){
    this->telephone = telephone;
}

string Store::getBtwNumber()
{
    return btwNumber;
}

void Store::setBtwNumber(string btwNumber){
    btwNumber = btwNumber;
}

string Store::getAdress(){
    return adress;
}

void Store::setAdress(string adress){
    this->adress = adress;
}

string Store::toString(){
    stringstream s;
    s << "Id: " << id << endl;
    s << "Naam: " << name << endl;
    s << "Adres: " << adress << endl;
    s << "Telefoonnummer: " << telephone << endl;
    s << "BTWnummer: " << btwNumber << endl;

    return s.str();
}



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    Store *test = new Store (4, "Test", "test", "test", "test");

    test->toString();
    system("Pause");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about `cout << test->toString();`?

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor is inversed: you are assigning member variables to constructor arguments and not vice versa.

```
nameS = name;
```

Should be

```
name = nameS;
```

And so on

Comment: This has helped me! Thank you very much. But in the classes exercises, I see that our teacher often uses the exact same members when assigning them into the constructor. How does this work actually? How does the compiler know what the actual member is?

Answer (score 2):

The method `toString` does work, but it won't magically decide to output its return value to screen. You'll have to do it yourself:

```
std::cout << test->toString() << std::endl;
```

You'll need to add `#include <iostream>` on top of your cpp file.

Comment: I seem to be close, but it still doesn't return me anything, except for boggus for the id-number?

Comment: See what @Desu_Never_Lies wrote for that. You also have some minor typos in the code, like using `naam` in place of `name` and a `::` which became `:`.